# Непонятное поведение тега a

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Проблема в следующем: почему тег `a` больше по размеру, чем картинка? Разве он не должен занимать высоту контента? На скриншоте видно, что он на пару пикселей больше, как от этого избавиться не указывая `max-height` & `height`?

Код:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="#">
  </a>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавьте картинке `display: block` . Изображения inline-элементы, поэтому у них как бы внизу место для выступающих элементов. Чтобы убрать - нужно сделать Блоковым элементом.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a {
  display: block;
  background: #f0f;
}

a img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/100" alt="#">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: вот чертовка!) чуть того, чуть другого. Или ты мужского пола?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае, чтобы решить проблему в пару пикселей, достаточно для **a** выставить `display: flex;` или `display: grid;`

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a {
  display: block;
}

.container a {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="#">
  </a>
</div>
```